# Delete a row in a referred table when a record from which the referred row is created is deleted. What is the parameter for sqlalchemy.Relationship?

Tags: sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

I am using `pydantic`, `sqlmodel`, `fastapi` and `python`.

I have a few tables, e.g. `Social`, `Email` that adds a new record to `VStatus` table whenever a new record is created in them, e.g. a new record in `Social` creates a corresponding record in `VStatus` table. The intent is to track the verification status of each record in these tables like `Social`, `Email` in the `VStatus` table.

Also, I want to delete the corresponding record in `VStatus` table whenever a record that created it e.g. in `Social` table is deleted.

How should I write the `sa_relationship_kwargs` for the Relationship in the 'parent' tables? E.g.

`Social` table:

```py
class Social(BaseUUIDModel, SocialBase, table=True):
    vstatus_id: Optional[UUID] = Field(
        default=None, foreign_key='VStatus.id', nullable=False)

    project: Optional["Project"] = Relationship(back_populates="socials")
    vstatus: "VStatus" = Relationship(
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "primaryjoin": "Social.vstatus_id==VStatus.id",
            'cascade': 'all, delete',
            'single_parent': True})
```

`VStatus` table:

```py
class VStatusBase(SQLModel):
    veri_status: VerificationStatusEnum = Field(
        default=VerificationStatusEnum.Unverified, nullable=False)
    vdesc: str = Field(default='', sa_column=Column("vdesc", String))
    # make it type Optional[bool] and default=None and let validator sets its
    # value
    is_verified: Optional[bool] = Field(default=False)


class VStatus(BaseUUIDModel, VStatusBase, table=True):
    # pass
    social: "Social" = Relationship(
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "primaryjoin": "VStatus.id==Social.vstatus_id",
            'cascade': 'all, delete, delete-orphan',
            'single_parent': True})  # need to have two ways one-to-one relationship
    # vstatus <-> social
    email: "Email" = Relationship(
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "primaryjoin": "VStatus.id==Email.vstatus_id",
            'cascade': 'all, delete, delete-orphan',
            'single_parent': True})
    coin: "Coin" = Relationship(
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "primaryjoin": "VStatus.id==Coin.vstatus_id",
            'cascade': 'all, delete, delete-orphan',
            'single_parent': True})
```

## Update 18 March 2023 SGT 1218AM

@daniil had asked me to provide a minimal viable example to reproduce my problem. Here it is:

```
from sqlmodel import SQLModel

class VStatusBase(SQLModel):
    veri_status: str = Field(
        default="Unverified", nullable=False)
    vdesc: str = Field(default='', sa_column=Column("vdesc", String))
    is_verified: Optional[bool] = Field(default=False)
    
class VStatus(VStatusBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
    social: "Social" = Relationship(
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "primaryjoin": "VStatus.id==Social.vstatus_id",
            'cascade': 'all, delete, delete-orphan',
            'single_parent': True})  # need to have two ways one-to-one relationship
            
class SocialBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(nullable=False)
    url: AnyHttpUrl = Field(
        nullable=False, sa_column_kwargs={'unique': True})

class Social(SocialBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(
            primary_key=True,
            index=True,
            nullable=False,
        )
    vstatus_id: Optional[UUID] = Field(
        default=None, foreign_key='VStatus.id', nullable=False)
    vstatus: "VStatus" = Relationship(
        sa_relationship_kwargs={
            "lazy": "selectin",
            "primaryjoin": "Social.vstatus_id==VStatus.id",
            'cascade': 'all, delete, delete-orphan',
            'single_parent': True})
```

From image below, we can see a record exists in the `Social` table.
[image]

From the image below, we can see that a corresponding record also exists in the `VStatus` table where `VStatus.id` = `Social.vstatus_id`.
[image]

I delete all the records (there is actually only one record) from the `Social` table.
[image]

I would expect the corresponding record in the `VStatus` table should be deleted but it doesn't, as shown.
[image]

Comment: Jim, may be you can check the discussion (https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/2718). Depends on one-to-one and many-to-manz and so on relationship, add "uselist" and "back_populates" fields.

Comment: I suggest you learn how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It helps you better understand the essence of your problem, it helps us figure out how to help you with that problem and it helps other readers transfer the example (and solution) to their specific problem. As it is right now, your code is not complete, not minimal and not reproducible. You have not shown any input/error message or input/output.

Comment: Hi @DaniilFajnberg, I have updated my question with a minimal viable codes and also attached screenshots showing the problem that I face, hope I can get the help needed.